# React Hook "useDispatch" is called in function "requestWithAction" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

when I am using react-redux(`"react-redux": "^7.2.2"`) to dispath action after fetched data from server like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import store from "../store";
import { getArticle } from "../action/ArticleAction";
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';


export function requestWithAction(config, action) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return axios(config).then(
    response => {
      const data = response.data.result;
      dispatch({ type: 'SUBMIT_DECISION' , payload: 1});
      //dispatch(action(data));
    }
  ).catch(
    error => {
      console.error(error);
    }
  );
}
```

shows error like this:

```
Failed to compile
src/common/XHRClient.js
  Line 20:20:  React Hook "useDispatch" is called in function "requestWithAction" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.
```

is it possible to dispath in the http response function? if I want to dispath after http response, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of options here:

1. You could pass your dispatch (from a react component) into this function and call it.
2. Since you have your store imported here you can remove the const dispatch = useDispatch(), and use store.dispatch({ type: 'SUBMIT_DECISION', payload: 1})